# Pandas group sum divided by unique items in group

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a data in excel of employees and no. of hours worked in a week. I tagged each employee to a project he/she is working on. I can get sum of hours worked in each project by doing groupby as below:

```
util_breakup_sum = df[["Tag", "Bill. Hours"]].groupby("Tag").sum()
    Bill. Hours
Tag                 
A61H           92.00
A63B          139.75
An             27.00
B32B           33.50
H              37.00
Manager         8.00
PP             23.00
RP0117         38.50
Se             37.50
```

However, when I try to calculate average time spent on each project per person, it gives me (sum/ total number of entries by employee), whereas correct average should be (sum / unique employee in group).
Example of mean is given below:

```
util_breakup_mean = df[["Tag", "Bill. Hours"]].groupby("Tag").mean()
     Bill. Hours
Tag                 
A61H        2.243902
A63B        1.486702
An          1.000000
B32B        0.712766
H           2.055556
Manager     0.296296
PP          1.095238
RP0117      1.425926
Se          3.750000
```

For example, group A61H has just two employees, so there average should be (92/2) = 46. However, the code is dividing by total number of entries by these employees and hence giving an average of 2.24.

How to get the average from unique employee names in the group?

Comment: You're going to need a column for some type of employee ID

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```py
df.groupby("Tag")["Bill. Hours"].sum().div(df.groupby("Tag")["Employee"].nunique()
```

Where `Employee` is column identifying employees.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `nunique`

```
util_breakup_mean = util_breakup_sum/df.groupby("Tag")['employee'].nunique()
```

Comment: Thanks but this returned all NaN values. I get the logic, but there seems to be some issue:
`A61H  A63B  An  B32B  Bill. Hours   H  Manager  PP  RP0117  Se
Tag                                                                    
A61H      NaN   NaN NaN   NaN          NaN NaN      NaN NaN     NaN NaN
A63B      NaN   NaN NaN   NaN          NaN NaN      NaN NaN     NaN NaN
An        NaN   NaN NaN   NaN          NaN NaN      NaN NaN     NaN NaN
B32B      NaN   NaN NaN   NaN          NaN NaN      NaN NaN     NaN NaN
H         NaN   NaN NaN   NaN          NaN NaN      NaN NaN  `